# Do you still get random world-spawn dragons after you kill Alduin?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have never killed Alduin in Skyrim because (a) who cares and (b) I am worried after Alduin dies there will no longer be random world-spawning dragon fights. And I love fighting dragons!

Based on the story in the game, the world should no longer be under siege by dragons after Alduin dies.  So, do the dragon attacks stop after you finish the main story line, or do they continue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on experience<sup>1</sup>, killing Alduin doesn't kill all of the dragons, so you will still find dragons roaming the province of Skyrim on your next adventure.

The goal of the game wasn't to just get rid of **ALL**<sup>2</sup> of the dragons. It was to only kill Alduin.

Killing Alduin only ends the Main Questline.

---

<sup>1</sup>The results might not work with everyone else.

<sup>2</sup>There are some other certain dragons besides Alduin that you have to kill in order to advance in the Main Questline.

Answer (score 2):

No, killing Alduin does not wipe out all dragons. Dragons with names and dragons at word walls can only be killed once.

Comment: The second part is not quite right, Dragons at word walls respawn after several days.

Comment: They respawn however they do not provide a new soul as you've already consumed their soul. I like to think of the dragons as a bit like eternal zombies. Even after they've been killed, they're not really dead and keep coming back, but they are missing something now that they just won't ever get back.